# How can I retrieve EditTexts and Spinners on a button click in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to get strings from EditTexts and a Spinner on a button click in a fragment.

I've written some code in an activity and that works but I can't figure out how to change it so it works in a fragment.

```
public void buttonClick (View view) {

    Spinner stars = findViewById(R.id.starsSpinner);
    String starsText = stars.getSelectedItem().toString();

    EditText time = findViewById(R.id.editTime);
    String timeText = time.getText().toString();

    EditText location = findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
    String locationText = location.getText().toString();

    String space = " ";

    String shareBody ="!r " + starsText + space + locationText + space + timeText;

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setClassName("com.discord", "com.discord.app.AppActivity$AppAction");
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, shareBody));

}
```

The code in the activity shares a string to the discord app. Every modification I've tried for the fragment just crashes the app.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is your code of the fragment? you have to put more details for us to help. Add the error displayed in the Logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't handle onclick  in a fragment like an activity
So you should delete this line from your xml:

```
        android:onClick="someMethod"
```

After that in your Fragment initialize your button object and call
its setOnClickListener method .

Have a look at this :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    //using findViewById() in a Fragment
    Button button=rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    
    //handle onclick events for the button
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTime);

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much you absolute genius. Works perfectly in that format. I'm very pleased to finally have the code working after pulling my hair out for ages. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Steve You're welcome.Please Accept the answer if it helped you